# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]:

Tags: php, laravel, kernel, laravel-blade

Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'NomComplet' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reclamation` (`NomComplet`, `Email`, `Message`) values (?, ?, ?))

Form:

[image]

Route:

[image]

Model:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

Comment: You need to put the code in the question itself as code blocks (not images). Also your form elements do not have `name=` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that the input

```
<input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Nom Complet">
```

You need to add a name attribute

```
<input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Nom Complet" name="NomComplet">
```

the same for email input and message

```
<input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Nom Complet" name="Email">
<textarea name="Message" id="msg"></textarea>
```

Becuase on tour controller you use

```
$req->NomComplet
$req->Email
$req->Message
```

This is case sensitive

Comment: i do it but 've the same prob on Message. [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Message' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reclamation` (`NomComplet`, `Email`, `Message`) values (Naim Salem, NaimS@outlook.fr, ?))

Comment: Maybe if you update your question adding code o imgaes to review I can help you